# multiple Python executables found in sys.path

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I use Anaconda to manage multiple virtual environments on a Windows machine. Within one of the virtual environments, I did the following test; and I found there are multiple python versions in the `sys.path`. My understanding is that it comes from multiple environments. Is this right, and will it cause any issue un-expected?

```
(test_kats) C:\>python
Python 3.7.9 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 13 2021, 19:28:53) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
...     print(p)
...

C:\spark\spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip
C:\spark\spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python
C:\Users\u\Anaconda3\envs\test_kats\python37.zip
C:\Users\u\Anaconda3\envs\test_kats\DLLs
C:\Users\u\Anaconda3\envs\test_kats\lib
C:\Users\u\Anaconda3\envs\test_kats
C:\Users\u\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
C:\Users\u\Anaconda3\envs\test_kats\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\u\Anaconda3\envs\test_kats\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\u\Anaconda3\envs\test_kats\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\u\Anaconda3\envs\test_kats\lib\site-packages\Py
```

Comment: There isn't a single executable in ``sys.path``. That's where *packages* are looked up – it's not the ``PATH`` environment variable. For example, ``C:\spark\spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python`` is a directory.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.path` is where Python will look for module and package imports (in their order of appearance).

1. The first path is always the current folder
2. Next comes the paths as defined in the `PYTHONPATH` system variable
3. Finally the paths to libraries and packages from your **active** conda environment, where
   ..\AppData\Roaming\Python.. comes from pip installs

The python.exe doesn't have to be on that path since it's already running.